# Deplhi TEmbeddedWB check if element is visible

Tags: delphi, element, visibility

I have EmbeddedWB component on Delphi form, and using it as webbrowser for different pages.

is there some way to check, if `IHTMLelement` is displayed or not?
I know about `ihtmlelement.style.display` property, and when it's set to 'none', then the element is not visible.
But what , if its parentelement, or parentelement's parentelement (etc etc...) is hidden?

Can i check somehow, if it's visible?

my code - that not works properly

```
var
document:ihtmldocument2;
body:ihtmlelement2;
i:integer;
tag:ihtmlelement;
tags:IHTMLElementCollection;

...

document:=embeddedwb.document as ihtmldocument2;
body:=document.body as ihtmlelement2;

if assigned(body) then begin

  Tags := Body.getElementsByTagName('*');

  for i := 0 to Tags.length-1 do
  begin

  try
    Tag := Tags.item(I, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;
    except
   tag:=nil;
    end;
  if tag.style.display<>'none' then begin
// this condition is not good, because the tag.style.display is usually set to '' so it not telling me, if the tag is really visible or not...
...


...
```

thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

ok I solved it...

added variable `tag2: IHTMLElement2;`

```
tag2:=tag as ihtmlelement2;

if tag2.currentstyle.display<>'none' then  ...
```

solved my problem

Comment: tag2 is IHTMLElement2 , tag is ITHMLElement.,  and ihtmlelement2 has property currentstyle, that show you the real display state of element